# VSTS API reference guide - page has disappeared?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I've been using this URL extensively but now it appears to redirect to another page which doesn't contain the pertinent information

This is the link in question:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/call-rest-api?view=vsts

But this is where it now takes you

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vsts/extend/reference/client/core-sdk?view=vsts

Where has the full reference gone???

Comment: Both the urls working fine. Could you check again?

Comment: No I meant the first URL simply redirects to the second

Comment: Both URLs worked just fine for me too.

Comment: Yeah both urls work fine and goes to the intended pages. Clear your browser cache and try again.

Comment: Sorry for the bad experience, we are checking this issue. Please use this link as a workaround for now: https://github.com/Microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk/tree/master/typings